# How can I create this linked list with stack in C?

Tags: c, list, stack

[image]

I can create the linked list. But I could not managed to create the stack with it. (Stack cannot be more than 5, and it can be empty as shown in the link). How can I do it? (C language but C++ functions like new int are allowed)

Comment: What language? Show us the code you have so far please

Comment: C language but C++ functions like new int are allowed @RobMullins

Comment: Are you trying to duplicate your linked list into a stack? Can you post the code you have for creating the stack, and what errors you are getting?

Comment: Linked list and stack will be together but not the same if you meant that. Like: Rob 1 2 5 -> HakunaMatata 6 7 9 
I could not write the code with stack. @RobMullins

Comment: I dont understand, if you are using a "new" anywhere, it is c++ , not c. Please understnad which language you are actually using. For a good way of telling, how are you invoking your compiler?

Answer (score 1):

The structure could be something like:

```
struct linkedStack {
  int elements[5];
  int top;
  struct linkedStack *next;
};
```

Then manage the stack with `top` (equals to zero at the beginning)...

Answer (score 1):

Post your code please so we can understand what you are trying to make.

This example can help you

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<process.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<alloc.h>

void Push(int, node **);
void Display(node **);
int Pop(node **);
int Sempty(node *);

typedef struct stack {
   int data;
   struct stack *next;
} node;


void main() {
   node *top;
   int data, item, choice;
   char ans, ch;

   clrscr();

   top = NULL;

   printf("\nStack Using Linked List : nn");
   do {
      printf("\n\n The main menu");
      printf("\n1.Push \n2.Pop \n3.Display \n4.Exit");
      printf("\n Enter Your Choice");
      scanf("%d", &choice);

      switch (choice) {
      case 1:
         printf("\nEnter the data");
         scanf("%d", &data);
         Push(data, &top);
         break;
      case 2:
         if (Sempty(top))
            printf("\nStack underflow!");
         else {
            item = Pop(&top);
            printf("\nThe popped node is%d", item);
         }
         break;
      case 3:
         Display(&top);
         break;
      case 4:
         printf("\nDo You want To Quit?(y/n)");
         ch = getche();
         if (ch == 'y')
            exit(0);
         else
            break;
      }

      printf("\nDo you want to continue?");
      ans = getche();
      getch();
      clrscr();
   } while (ans == 'Y' || ans == 'y');
   getch();
}

void Push(int Item, node **top) {
   node *New;
   node * get_node(int);
   New = get_node(Item);
   New->next = *top;
   *top = New;
}

node * get_node(int item) {
   node * temp;
   temp = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));
   if (temp == NULL)
      printf("\nMemory Cannot be allocated");
   temp->data = item;
   temp->next = NULL;
   return (temp);
}

int Sempty(node *temp) {
   if (temp == NULL)
      return 1;
   else
      return 0;
}

int Pop(node **top) {
   int item;
   node *temp;
   item = (*top)->data;
   temp = *top;
   *top = (*top)->next;
   free(temp);
   return (item);
}

void Display(node **head) {
   node *temp;
   temp = *head;
   if (Sempty(temp))
      printf("\nThe stack is empty!");
   else {
      while (temp != NULL) {
         printf("%d\n", temp->data);
         temp = temp->next;
      }
   }
   getch();
}
```